# ChromeCast delegates are not called when the app is in the background

Tags: ios, objective-c, chromecast, google-cast

I am working on an application in which I will connect to the T.V using ChromeCast device, to achieve this I have used GoogleCast FrameWork in my project,

I am facing a problem when my app goes to background

Am writing piece code in this method for calling a method to mute the audio

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application  {

    HomeViewController *lHomeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];

    _mediaControlChannel = [[GCKMediaControlChannel alloc] init];

    [lHomeViewController muteAudio];

}
```

It calls the method in the home view controller, where in which I wrote the below code

```
-(void) muteAudio {

    [self.deviceManager setMuted:YES];

}
```

But the audio is not muted and it is not calling the below delegate method.

```
- (void)mediaControlChannelDidUpdateStatus:(GCKMediaControlChannel *)mediaControlChannel
```

Please suggest me

Comment: You are creating a new instance of the HomeViewController in applicationDidEnterBackGround. You need to send the muteAudio message to the running instance of HomeViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of the `HomeViewController` in the `applicationDidEnterBackground` app delegate method. You need to send the `muteAudio` message to the running instance of `HomeViewController`.

For this, the best solution would be to use `NSNotificationCenter`.

In your HomeViewController's `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` method, use the following line:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                         selector: @selector(muteAudio) 
                                             name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                           object: nil];
```

This will automatically call the muteAudio method when the application enters background.

Read more about NSNotificationCenter [here](http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/).

Read more about the application status notifications [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification).